# Sbt plugin for jruby

Tags: maven-2, scala, jruby, sass, sbt

Is there a plugin for sbt available which automatically installs JRuby and adds some hooks to automatically run scripts at certain points (e.g. before compilation).

Background: For a (lift) project, I want to use [sass](http://sass-lang.com/), or more specifically, [compass](http://compass-style.org/) as a tool for generating the css. A Java or Scala clone of sass would not be enough, unfortunately.

Of course, It wouldn’t be a problem at all to just generate the css manually and then put both inside the repository and no-one ever needs to care about it.

On the other hand, to ease development on several systems, I’d rather have a clear dependency inside sbt which simply does the work.

Is there any way to achieve this?
Or generally: Is there a way to run JRuby scripts from inside Scala?

**Edit** Added maven-2 to the tags. Maybe there is a maven repo for JRuby which allows me to deliver and use it somehow.

Comment: There's http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jruby/

Comment: Great. Now, how would I use this to install and execute gems via bundler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's perhaps not the most elegant solution, you can always call external scripts using the Process support in SBT.

```
import sbt._
import Process._

class Project(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info) {
  lazy val runSomething = task {
    "ruby somescript.rb" ! log
    None
  }
}
```

There's a bit more info about the external process support available here: http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Process

Comment: But unfortunately, it requires ruby being installed. I’d rather have sbt handle all dependencies.

Comment: Fair enough. Adding jruby as a dependency should be easy enough, but getting SBT to call it will take a bit more work. I would probably reach for the scripting API, but I haven't used it in far too long, so whipping together an example would take a bit. I'd like to have this option, so I'll investigate and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Try my [sbt plugin](https://github.com/banshee/sbt-jruby) from github.  It's very bare-bones for now, but it should download the jruby jar and allow you to call a .rb file before compiling.

The guts of the plugin are really simple:

```
    import sbt._

    object SbtJRuby extends Plugin {
      object SbtJRubySettings {
        lazy val settings = Seq(Keys.commands += jirb, tx, jrubyFile := file("fnord.rb"))
      }

      def jirb = Command.args("jirb", "<launch jirb>") { (state, args) =>
        org.jruby.Main.main(List("-S", "jirb").toArray[String])
        state
      }

      val jruby = TaskKey[Unit]("jruby", "run a jruby file")
      val jrubyFile = SettingKey[File]("jruby-file", "path to file to run with JRuby")

      val tx = jruby <<= (jrubyFile, Keys.baseDirectory) map { (f: File, b: File) =>
        val rb = (b / f.toString).toString
        //    println("jruby with " + rb)
        org.jruby.Main.main(List(rb).toArray[String])
      }
    }
```

Really all it's doing is calling the jruby jar file with the name of the rb file you've passed in.  And of course adding jruby itself as a managed dependency:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.jruby" % "jruby-complete" % "1.6.5"
)
```

It also adds a "jirb" command to the Scala console that puts you into a jirb session.